# Is there a way to create a new, pre-populated field within a view (Feature Layer), in Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, python, field-calculator, sql

In SQL, users can write a SELECT statement that 'invents' a new field with a default value already populated in it, for all records returned. In the example below, the field `Type` doesn't actually exist in any table but is made-up as a part of the query:

```
SELECT
  ID
  , 'Reptile' AS Type
  , Species
FROM AnimalsTable
WHERE Species IN ('Snake', 'Turtle', 'Lizard');
```

The query above returns a table like this:

```
ID  |  Type    |  Species
---------------------------
4   |  Reptile |  Turtle
6   |  Reptile |  Snake
8   |  Reptile |  Lizard
12  |  Reptile |  Turtle
13  |  Reptile |  Turtle
18  |  Reptile |  Lizard
```

Is there a similar way to call a feature class in Python that gives this kind of ability?

Background: in ArcGIS 10.7, I have a script that's designed to truncate an SDE feature class & then append 200,000+ records from three other feature classes (from a mix of SDE, .shp, file-geodatabase types), and *all* of the resulting records in the updated SDE feature class need to have the exact same value in a single field (my `STATUS` field needs to be staged with `Incomplete`, for all of them). I can't add the field & attributes to all three source data sets. The only arcpy options I can see, all require using CalculateField_management, which takes *forever*! Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the data source type (shapefile, file geodatabase, enterprise geodatabase,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to add the default value `Incomplete` to the `STATUS` field of the feature class after you truncate it. With arcpy you can do it like this,

```
arcpy.AssignDefaultToField_management(
    outFeatureClass,
    'STATUS', 
    'Incomplete'
)
```

[AcrGIS Docs - Assign default to field](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/assign-default-to-field.htm)

Comment: This may be a feasible option but there is one complication to it: sometimes my input feature classes have a field called "STATUS" as well. So, I'd have to add code to (1) make them into a feature layer and then (2) hide those fields, if/when they exist. Otherwise the appended records would inherit the values coming from the source data instead of the default value.

Comment: Obrigado, @cabesuon - I will mark this as 'the answer', although I didn't end up going this route. I found an issue with the CalculateField_management() portion of my script that, once corrected, completed the field-calculate operation in a tolerable amount of time (about 4 minutes). In fact, I'm fairly certain that my erroneous code ran in a way that it appeared to be still working on the field-calculation, but was actually 'stuck' in an un-handled error (it never completed for me...I just had to 'End Task' after I lost patience).